# Object that flows with site

Tags: jquery, html, css

how is this made?

http://www.axxamo.de/

It would be nice if someone could tell me whats the technik is, that the navbar flows with the window-top-border when you scroll?
Query? or only css?

Thank you,

Daniel

Comment: its not css, and i dont know with wich jquery file (there are nearbey 6 its made)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use a technique called "Floating Navigation Bar"

You can find a tutorial for this here:[Floating Navigation Bar](http://liljosh.com/how-to-build-a-floating-navigation-when-scrolling/)

Comment: no matter how bad the question is, this is the true answer + 1